# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while using docker-java

Tags: java, docker

We are using this library to do 'docker pull' from docker hub and to check whether an image with a given name already exists. We need this to work in Linux, Mac and Windows having the latest version of docker installed. But in several cases, we have hit the error mentioned in the title and that error is coming from jersey-client that is internally used by this library.
We have tested using docker-java 3.1.5 and the latest 3.2.5 and on docker 19.03.5 and also the latest docker. The latest docker version varies on different platforms as mentioned below:

Linux (19.03.12)
Mac (19.03.8)
Windows (19.03.8)

[Attached result of our tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AARj.png)

I am sharing a code snippet of what we are trying:

```
DockerClient dockerClient;

dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance().build();

String imageName = "SOME_IMAGE_NAME";
List images = dockerClient.listImagesCmd().withImageNameFilter(imageName).exec();
if(!images.isEmpty()){
dockerClient.removeImageCmd(images.get(0).getId());
}
dockerClient.pullImageCmd(imageName).exec(new PullImageResultCallback()).awaitCompletion(DOCKER_PULL_WAIT_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

We are using Java 8.

If anyone has faced this kind of an issue before and solved it, can you please suggest how we should approach this problem?

Sharing the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
2020-07-13 22:14:59,255 ERROR [docker-java-stream--1445483847]  ResultCallbackTemplate -   Error during callback
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:122) ~[jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:?]
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:91) ~[jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:?]
        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:69) ~[jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:2.1.6]
        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:80) ~[jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:2.1.6]
        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:99) ~[jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:2.1.6]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.<init>(JerseyWebTarget.java:48) ~[jersey-client-2.30.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:274) ~[jersey-client-2.30.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:56) ~[jersey-client-2.30.1.jar:?]
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerHttpClient.execute(JerseyDockerHttpClient.java:291) ~[docker-java-transport-jersey-3.2.5.jar:?]
        at com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:228) ~[docker-java-core-3.2.5.jar:?]
        at com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:269) ~[docker-java-core-3.2.5.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.57]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:62) ~[jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:?]
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:155) ~[jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:?]
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:105) ~[jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:?]
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: You need to show the entire exception message and stack trace

Comment: Hi @tgdavies I have added the stack trace. The docker-java uses jersey-client as transport by default. I have received a feedback elsewhere that if we change it to some other transport (recommended apache httpclient 5), the problem may be resolved (https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docs/transports.md#apache-httpclient-5). However, when I am trying to follow steps mentioned at https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md  it is failing compilation because it is not allowing me to pass 2 arguments in DockerClientImpl.getInstance call.

Comment: I am trying to find a working example of how to correctly use a non-default transport.

Comment: Using Apache httpclient 5 as transport with docker-java is working on Ubuntu and Windows on different docker versions. We will test on Mac and ttry out a few different scenarios. If all our tests work, I will post the solution and close this question. Thanks for helping @tgdavies

Answer (score 0):

The default transport that is used by docker-java library is jersey-client which has issues on non-Unix platforms. For that I had to explicitly use a different transport. I used Apache httpclient 5 which is anyway planned to be made default in the future releases of docker-java.
A list of transports for docker-java can be found at https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docs/transports.md .